# Pass jQuery variable to PHP Symfony2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, rating

I'm trying to do a star rating tutorial with Symfony2

In `rating.css`:

```
fieldset, label { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body{ margin: 20px; }
h1 { font-size: 1.5em; margin: 10px; }

.rating {
    border: none;
    float: left;
}

.rating > input { display: none; }
.rating > label:before {
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    display: inline-block;
    content: "\f005";
}

.rating > .half:before {
    content: "\f089";
    position: absolute;
}

.rating > label {
    color: #ddd;
    float: right;
}

.rating > input:checked ~ label,
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover,
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label { color: #FFD700;  }

.rating > input:checked + label:hover,
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label,
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #FFED85;  }
```

In View `test.html.twig`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/hearwegohearwego/css/rating.css') }}" />
    <script src="{{ asset('bundles/hearwegohearwego/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#demo1 .stars").click(function () {
                var id=$(this).attr('id');
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ path('test') }}",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {id1:id},
                    success: function(result)
                    {
                        alert(id);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<fieldset id='demo1' class="rating">
    <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" />
    <label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" />
    <label class = "full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" />
    <label class = "full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
    <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" />
    <label class = "full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
    <input class="stars" type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" />
    <label class = "full" for="star1" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
</fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

In `DefaultController.php` (in right folder declared in `test.html.twig` script):

```
/**
     * @Route("/test", name="test")
     */
    public function testAction(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $b=$request->get('id1');
            echo $b;
        }
        return $this->render('HearWeGoHearWeGoBundle::test.html.twig');
    }
```

When I click on stars, it does alert with a message contaning variable `id` in jQuery script, but nothing is echoed as I want. Please help me solve this problem, after that, I will use this tutorial for rating in my database in Symfony2

Comment: are you sure this is not working? I copied and past this code in my project and alert the value of start clicked!!

Comment: I did say it in my question. It does alert, but does not echo the variable I want to echo

Comment: The real question of this article is, how to pass variable from my jQuery script to Controller of my Bundle, then handle it

Comment: Just FYI, it's a _JavaScript_ variable, not jQuery. Also, I fail to see how CSS is relevant to the question.

Comment: Yes, I just post CSS file for imagining all relevant files of star rating :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript change success function:

```
                success: function (result)
                {
                    alert(result)
                    console.log(result)
                }
```

and in controller:

```
public function testAction(Request $request)
    {
//        print_r($request);
        if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
            $b=$request->request->get('id1');
            echo $b;
        }
        return new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response();
    }
```

it alert star passed to server

Comment: It's nothing different from my code. My code DOES ALERT STAR PASSED. The real question is HOW TO ECHO THAT VARIABLE `$b`. If I know it, then I can get the star clicked on, use it to handle and store in my database. It I need to alert it, I already did it before I post this question here. The thing I need is to store it in my database through Symfony

Comment: It is echo that code!!!which entity is related to this id1 that you want tot save it?

Comment: What? When I run it, it echoed nothing! The Entity I intend to use to save it is `Rating`, its attributes include `id`, `audio_id`, `user_id`, `stars`, `created_at`